# My first Hello World from a module and model and I can't load the model

Tags: module, magento-1, model

This is my first module. The module loads and the index controller executes. I am failing loading my first "hello world" model.
I cleared the cache and turned off caching.

I included all the code below, the 2 config files, the controller and the model

I have been working on this for 2 days reading all I can trying every version of upper and lower case. It must be something simple that I am overlooking. Help

thanks

**app/etc/modules/Nat_Products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<config>  
    <modules>  
        <Nat_Products>  
            <active>true</active>  
            <codePool>local</codePool>  
        </Nat_Products>  
    </modules>  
</config>
```

=====

**app/code/local/Nat/Products/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"? >  
<config >      
    <modules >  
        <Nat_Products >  
            <version >0.1.0</version >  
        </Nat_Products >  
    </modules >  

    <global >  
        <models >  
            <nat_products >  
                <class >Nat_Products_Model</class >  
            </nat_products >  
        </models >  
    </global >          

    <frontend >  
        <routers >  
            <addproduct >  
                <use >standard</use >  
                <args >  
                    <module >Nat_Products</module >  
                    <frontName >addproduct</frontName >  
                </args >  
            </addproduct >  
        </routers >    
    </frontend >      
</config >
```

=====

**app/code/local/Nat/Products/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php  

class Nat_Products_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {  
    public function indexAction() {  

        echo 'Hello World from ' . __CLASS__ . "<br\>";  

        $product = Mage::getModel("products/addproduct");  // returns false  
        echo $product->hello();  
    }  
}
```

=====

**app/code/local/Nat/Products/Model/Addproduct.php**

```
<?php  
class Nat_Products_Model_Addproduct extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract  
{  

    public function hello()  
    {  
        return "hello world from " .__CLASS__;  
    }  

}
```

=========

I run maglocal.com/addproduct
 result of run is:

> Hello World from Nat_Products_IndexController   ( ! ) Fatal error:
>   Call to a member function hello() on a non-object in
>   maglocal.com\app\code\local\Nat\Products\controllers\IndexController.php
>   on line 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should instantiate your model like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel("nat_products/addproduct");
```

The part before the slash is the tag you set in your module under the `<models>` tag:

```
<models>
    <nat_products><!-- THIS ONE -->
        <class>Nat_Products_Model</class>
    </nat_products>
</models>
```