# Magento can't find the class model

Tags: magento-1.9, module, model

I am new with Magento. And trying to create my own model.
So I start with a small test 
The model folder structure as the following:

```
FirstStore/Demo/block 
FirstStore/Demo/etc/config.xml
FirstStore/Demo/controller
FirstStore/Demo/Model/Product.php
FirstStore/Demo/Helper
FirstStore/Demo/sql
```

the `etc/config.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</modules>
</config>
```

and the  `Model/Product.php` code:

```
class FirstStore_Demo_Model_Product
{
public function sayhello(){
    echo 'Hello , World with Magento';
}
}
```

and the  `app/etc/modules/FirstStore_Demo.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <FirstStore_Demo>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </FirstStore_Demo>
</modules>
</config>
```

finally I am running this code under test.php page at the magento root dir
 
the  `test.php` code:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$product = new FirstStore_Demo_Model_Product;
$product->sayhello();
```

the error at `localhost/magento/test.php` is:

> Fatal error: Class 'FirstStore_Demo_Model_Product' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\magento\test.php

Comment: is your `FirstStore` folder located in `app/code/local` or at least `app/code/community` ?

Comment: please add replace your `config.xml` with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <FirstStore_Demo>
<modules>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</modules>
   </FirstStore_Demo>
<global><models><firststore_demo><class>FirstStore_Demo_Model</class></firststore_demo></models></global>
</config>` and call the model with `$product = Mage::getModel('firststore_demo/product');` to see what happens

Comment: @Marius at `app/code/local`

Comment: @SanderMangel still not working, but there is a new error there :: Fatal error: Call to a member function sayhello() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\magento\test.php the new code is `$product = Mage::getModel('FirstStore_Demo/Product');
$product->sayhello();`

Comment: What version of PHP are you running and did you include any projects from `Hackathon` or `Aitoc`?

Comment: @SanderMangel no I didn't include any project and my php v is 5.6.8

Comment: Magento does not yet officially support PHP 5.6 so that might be the issue.
http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

Answer (score 2):

Magento does not yet support PHP 5.6 officially as the version you stated using in your comments. Please check the [System Requirements page](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) for supported software.

Especially in combination with XAMPP it might cause unexpected issues. I would advice you to downgrade to PHP 5.5.

Comment: I did not think so. could you check magento PHP versions supported [http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html#php-support](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html#php-support)

Comment: Ah, that link might be outdated. Have you tried your script on a Linux installation? I can't reproduce your error

Answer (score 0):

Your model file, does not seem to extends the core class don't forget extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract in the definition of your model class..
so it would be

```
class FirstStore_Demo_Model_Product extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function sayhello(){
        echo 'Hello , World with Magento';
    }
}
```

Moreover you need to add your model declaration in your config.xml as someone wisely suggested

```
<models>

          <firststore_demo>
                   <class>FirstStore_Demo_Model</class>
          </firststore_demo>
</models>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could solve this using routers, take a look to this question and its answer.

[My first Hello World from a module and model and I can't load the model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/my-first-hello-world-from-a-module-and-model-and-i-cant-load-the-model#answer-8571)

Answer (score -1):

You ought to try

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('firststore_demo/product');
```

And add to your config.xml

```
<models>

          <firststore_demo>
                   <class>FirstStore_Demo_Model</class>
          </firststore_demo>
</models>
```

Comment: Was suggested in the comments, didnt work :)

Comment: $productModel->sayhello();

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function sayhello() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\magento\test.php`

Comment: what output - var_dump($productModel);    ?

Comment: @Mick `bool(false)`